# MVC3 Razor View PopUps

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, modal-dialog

I am using jquery modal popup in my application with MVC3 Razor view.

Issue is I need to open popup once I click on Menu Options, these Menu options are there in Layeout page (coz I need to show it throughout the site). As I have to have the popup html code at layeout, so it is appearing as hidden in all page sources.

So is there any better way through which I can create popup html at run time only?

I using this right now:

```
$(id).dialog({
            closeOnEscape: true,
            draggable: true,
            resizable: false,
            dialogClass: clz,
            modal: true,
            title: $(id + ' .dialog-content').attr('title'),
            closeText: ''
        });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [JQuery UI Dialog plugin](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-form) and use it  to load the modal dialog via ajax

*Example*

```
$('#MyAtag').click(function () {
// Add a container for the modal dialog, or get the existing one
var dialog = ($('#ModalDialog').length > 0) ? $('#ModalDialog') : $('<div id="ModalDialog" style="display:hidden"></div>').appendTo('body');
// load the data via ajax
$.get( 'mycontroller/myaction', {},
    function (responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
        dialog.html(responseText);
        dialog.dialog({
            bgiframe: true,
            modal: true,
            width: 940,
            title: 'My Title'
        }); 
    }
);
});
```

which binds a call to an ajax 'get' to the 'click' event of a link. The ajax get request returns a partial view from the corresponding action in you MVC project, which then shows up in the modal dialog.

*Here is a rough example of what the controller could look like:*

```
public ActionResult MyAction()
{
    // Do Some stuff
    //...

    // If the request is an ajax one, return the partial view
    if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        return PartialView("PartialViewName");

    // Else return the normal view
    return View();
}
```

Is it what you want ?

Comment: okay, thanks, so if I need a 'form' in popup then I need to write html for it in partial view returned by 'mycontroller/myaction'?

Comment: somehow 'dialog.html(responseText)' is not appending retured response..therefor I am seeing blank popup..